# AddHandler is not working

Tags: vb.net, addhandler

Why is my addhandler not firing?

In the Sub "CreateTagStyle", the AddHandler is not firing when the LinkButton is clicked. Is there some reason that addhandlers can't be added at certain points of the page lifecycle?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/_Common/Admin.master" %>

<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs)
        If Not e.IsFromDetailTable Then
            Dim forms As New MB.RequestFormPacket()
            RadGrid1.DataSource = forms.GetPackets()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_DetailTableDataBind(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs)
        Select Case e.DetailTableView.Name
            Case "gtvForms"
                Dim PacketID As Guid = e.DetailTableView.ParentItem.GetDataKeyValue("ID")
                e.DetailTableView.DataSource = MB.RequestForm.GetRequestForms(PacketID)
        End Select
    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_InsertCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs)
        If IsValid Then
            Select Case TryCast(e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer, GridTableView).Name
                Case "gtvPackets"
                    Dim rtbName As RadTextBox = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("rtbName"), RadTextBox)
                    Dim IsActive As Boolean = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("cbxIsActive"), CheckBox).Checked

                    Dim packet As New MB.RequestFormPacket()
                    packet.Name = rtbName.Text
                    packet.IsActive = IsActive
                    packet.Insert()

                    e.Canceled = True
                    e.Item.OwnerTableView.IsItemInserted = False
                    RadGrid1.Rebind()
                    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "ClientMessage", "SuccessMessage('Request Form Packet has been added successfully.');", True)
                Case "gtvForms"
                    Dim parentItem As GridDataItem = e.Item.OwnerTableView.ParentItem
                    Dim rcbForms As RadComboBox = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("rcbForms"), RadComboBox)

                    Dim rf As New MB.RequestForm()
                    rf.RequestFormPacketID = CType(parentItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(parentItem.ItemIndex)("ID"), Guid)
                    rf.FormID = rcbForms.SelectedValue

                    If MB.RequestFormPacket.HasItems(rf.RequestFormPacketID) Then
                        rf.SortOrder = rf.MaxSortOrder + 1
                    Else
                        rf.SortOrder = 0
                    End If

                    rf.Insert()

                    e.Canceled = True
                    e.Item.OwnerTableView.IsItemInserted = False
                    TryCast(e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer, GridTableView).Rebind()
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs)
        If IsValid Then
            Select Case TryCast(e.Item.NamingContainer, GridTableView).Name
                Case "gtvPackets"
                    Dim PacketID As Guid = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Button).NamingContainer, GridEditFormItem).GetDataKeyValue("ID")
                    Dim Name As String = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("rtbName"), RadTextBox).Text
                    Dim Tags As String = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("hdnTags"), HiddenField).Value
                    Dim IsActive As Boolean = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("cbxIsActive"), CheckBox).Checked
                    Dim rfp As New MB.RequestFormPacket()
                    rfp.Update(PacketID, Name, IsActive)
                    Call MB.RequestFormPacketTag.Insert(PacketID, Tags)
                    e.Item.Edit = False
                    TryCast(e.Item.NamingContainer, GridTableView).Rebind()
                    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "ClientMessage", "SuccessMessage('Request Form Packet has been updated successfully.');", True)
                Case "gtvForms"
                    Dim RequestFormID As Guid = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Button).NamingContainer, GridEditFormItem).GetDataKeyValue("ID")
                    Dim rcbForms As RadComboBox = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("rcbForms"), RadComboBox)
                    Dim rf As New MB.RequestForm()
                    rf.Update(RequestFormID, rcbForms.SelectedValue)
                    e.Item.Edit = False
                    TryCast(e.Item.NamingContainer, GridTableView).Rebind()
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_DeleteCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs)
        Dim editedItem As GridEditableItem = TryCast(e.Item, GridEditableItem)
        Select Case CType(editedItem.Parent.Parent, GridTableView).Name
            Case "gtvPackets"
                Dim ID As Guid = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, ImageButton).NamingContainer, GridDataItem).GetDataKeyValue("ID")
                MB.RequestFormPacket.Delete(ID)
                System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "ClientMessage", "NotifyMessage('Request Form Packet has been deleted.');", True)
            Case "gtvForms"
                Dim ID As Guid = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, ImageButton).NamingContainer, GridDataItem).GetDataKeyValue("ID")
                MB.RequestForm.Delete(ID)
                System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "ClientMessage", "NotifyMessage('Request Form has been removed.');", True)
        End Select
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ibnItemUpArrow_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)
        Dim gtv As GridTableView = CType(CType(sender, ImageButton).NamingContainer.NamingContainer, GridTableView)
        Dim ID As Guid = New Guid(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
        Call MB.RequestForm.MoveUp(ID)
        gtv.Rebind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ibnItemDownArrow_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)
        Dim gtv As GridTableView = CType(CType(sender, ImageButton).NamingContainer.NamingContainer, GridTableView)
        Dim ID As Guid = New Guid(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
        Call MB.RequestForm.MoveDown(ID)
        gtv.Rebind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_RowDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridDragDropEventArgs)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.HtmlElement) Then
            If e.DraggedItems(0).OwnerGridID = RadGrid1.ClientID Then
                If e.DestDataItem IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim gtv As GridTableView = CType(e.DestDataItem.NamingContainer, GridTableView)
                    For Each gdi As GridDataItem In e.DraggedItems
                        Select Case gtv.Name
                            Case "gtvForms"
                                MB.RequestForm.DragAndDropReorder(gdi.GetDataKeyValue("ID"), e.DestDataItem.GetDataKeyValue("ID"), IIf(e.DropPosition = GridItemDropPosition.Above, True, False))
                                gtv.Rebind()
                        End Select
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub cbxAllowDragAndDrop_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim cbx As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)
        If cbx.Checked Then
            RadGrid1.ClientSettings.AllowRowsDragDrop = True
            RadGrid1.ClientSettings.Selecting.AllowRowSelect = True
            RadGrid1.ClientSettings.Selecting.EnableDragToSelectRows = True
        Else
            RadGrid1.ClientSettings.AllowRowsDragDrop = False
            RadGrid1.ClientSettings.Selecting.AllowRowSelect = False
            RadGrid1.ClientSettings.Selecting.EnableDragToSelectRows = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ibnDisableToggleProcess_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)
        Dim ibn As ImageButton = CType(sender, ImageButton)
        Dim hdn As HiddenField = CType(ibn.NamingContainer.FindControl("hdnDisableProcessID"), HiddenField)
        Dim status As Boolean = MB.RequestFormPacket.ActivateToggle(New Guid(hdn.Value))
        Dim gtv As GridTableView = CType(ibn.NamingContainer.NamingContainer, GridTableView)
        gtv.Rebind()
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "ClientMessage", "SuccessMessage('Process has been " & IIf(status, "Activated", "Deactivated") & ".');", True)
    End Sub

    Protected Function DisplayTagList(ByVal tags As IEnumerable(Of MB.RequestFormPacketTag)) As String
        Dim list As String = ""
        For Each t As MB.RequestFormPacketTag In tags
            list += "<span class=""tags"">" & t.Tag.Name & "</span>"
        Next
        Return list
    End Function

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs)
        Select Case e.Item.GetType.Name
            Case "GridEditFormInsertItem"
                'do nothing
            Case "GridEditFormItem"
                Dim plh As PlaceHolder = CType(e.Item.FindControl("plhTags"), PlaceHolder)
                Dim hdn As HiddenField = CType(e.Item.FindControl("hdnTags"), HiddenField)
                If hdn IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim gefi As GridEditFormItem = e.Item
                    Dim packet As MB.RequestFormPacket = gefi.DataItem
                    For Each pt As MB.RequestFormPacketTag In packet.RequestFormPacketTags
                        Call CreateTagStyle(plh, hdn, pt.Tag.Name)
                        If hdn.Value = "" Then
                            hdn.Value = "|"
                        End If
                        hdn.Value += pt.Tag.Name & "|"
                    Next
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnAddTag_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim btnAddTag As Button = sender
        Dim rtbTags As RadTextBox = btnAddTag.NamingContainer.FindControl("rtbTags")
        Dim plhTags As PlaceHolder = btnAddTag.NamingContainer.FindControl("plhTags")
        Dim hdnTags As HiddenField = btnAddTag.NamingContainer.FindControl("hdnTags")
        Dim TagExists As Boolean = False

        rtbTags.Text = rtbTags.Text.ToUpper().Trim()

        Dim currentTags() As String = Split(hdnTags.Value, "|")

        For i As Integer = 1 To currentTags.Count - 2
            Call CreateTagStyle(plhTags, hdnTags, currentTags(i))
        Next

        If TagExists = False And String.IsNullOrEmpty(rtbTags.Text) = False Then
            Call CreateTagStyle(plhTags, hdnTags, rtbTags.Text)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnTags.Value) Then
                hdnTags.Value = "|"
            End If
            hdnTags.Value += rtbTags.Text & "|"
            'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "ClientMessage", "highlightTag('" & lbn.ClientID & "');", True)
        End If

        rtbTags.Text = ""
        rtbTags.Focus()
    End Sub

    Public Sub RemoveTag(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Response.End()
        Dim lbnSender As LinkButton = sender
        Dim plhTags As PlaceHolder = lbnSender.NamingContainer.FindControl("plhTags")
        Dim hdnTags As HiddenField = lbnSender.NamingContainer.FindControl("hdnTags")
        Response.Write(hdnTags.Value)
        Response.End()
        Dim TagExists As Boolean = False
        Dim currentTags() As String = Split(hdnTags.Value, "|")
        For i As Integer = 1 To currentTags.Count - 2
            Call CreateTagStyle(plhTags, hdnTags, currentTags(i))
        Next
    End Sub

    Protected Sub CreateTagStyle(ByVal plh As PlaceHolder, ByVal hdn As HiddenField, ByVal tagName As String)
        Dim lbn As New LinkButton()
        lbn.ID = "lbn_" & hdn.ClientID & "_" & tagName
        lbn.CssClass = "deleteCreateTag"
        lbn.Text = "X"
        AddHandler lbn.Click, AddressOf RemoveTag
        plh.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<div><span class=showTag>" & tagName & "</span>"))
        plh.Controls.Add(lbn)
        plh.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</div>"))
    End Sub

</script>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .tags
        {
            border:solid 1px #93AFE5;
            background-color:#F3F7F8;
            margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
            padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:10px;
            text-transform:uppercase;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function highlightTag(id) {
            $("#" + id).highlightFade({ color: '#FFFF99', speed: 2000, iterator: 'sinusoidal' });
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" EnableAJAX="false">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

    <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" />

    <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" Skin="WebBlue" style="position:relative;top:1px;" ValidationGroup="vgTabs">
        <Tabs>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Request Form Packets" Selected="true" ImageUrl="~/Admin/Images/Packet2.png" />
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Request Forms" NavigateUrl="Forms.aspx" ImageUrl="~/Admin/Images/Forms.png" />
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsForms" runat="server" TypeName="MB.Form" SelectMethod="GetForms" />

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlContent" runat="server" CssClass="ContentPanel">

        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" GridLines="None"
                OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
                AllowAutomaticUpdates="true"
                AllowAutomaticDeletes="true"
                AllowAutomaticInserts="true"
                OnInsertCommand="RadGrid1_InsertCommand"
                OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid1_UpdateCommand"
                OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid1_DeleteCommand"
                OnRowDrop="RadGrid1_RowDrop"
                OnDetailTableDataBind="RadGrid1_DetailTableDataBind" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">

            <%-----------------------------------------------------------%>
            <%------------------------- PACKETS -------------------------%>
            <%-----------------------------------------------------------%>
            <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" ClientDataKeyNames="ID"
                    ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true" Name="gtvPackets"
                    NoMasterRecordsText="There are currently no Request Form Packets"
                    GroupLoadMode="Client"
                    RetrieveNullAsDBNull="true"
                    CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                    AllowAutomaticUpdates="true"
                    AllowAutomaticDeletes="true"
                    AllowAutomaticInserts="true">

                <RowIndicatorColumn>
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                </RowIndicatorColumn>

                <ExpandCollapseColumn>
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                </ExpandCollapseColumn>

                <CommandItemTemplate>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="AdminGridHeader">&nbsp;<img src="../Admin/Images/Packet2.png" align="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Request Form Packets</td>
                            <td width="1%"><asp:CheckBox ID="cbxAllowDragAndDrop" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbxAllowDragAndDrop_CheckedChanged" /></td>
                            <td width="1%" nowrap="nowrap"><asp:Label AssociatedControlID="cbxAllowDragAndDrop" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enable Drag and Drop Reordering" ToolTip="Drag and Drop Reordering applies only to Forms." /></td>
                            <td align="right" width="1%"><asp:Button ID="btnAddPacket" Text="Create New Packet" runat="server" CommandName="InitInsert" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </CommandItemTemplate>

                <EditFormSettings>
                    <EditColumn ButtonType="PushButton" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" />
                </EditFormSettings>

                <EditItemStyle Font-Bold="true" BackColor="#FFFFCC"  />

                <Columns>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Packet Name" UniqueName="PacketName" SortExpression="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img src="../Admin/Images/Packet2.png" align="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<%#Eval("Name")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="rtbName" Width="300" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="rtbName" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Tags" UniqueName="Tags">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#DisplayTagList(Eval("RequestFormPacketTags"))%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddTags" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnAddTag">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="rtbTags" runat="server" Width="200" style="text-transform:uppercase;" />
                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revTags" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Entry" ControlToValidate="rtbTags" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^[^<>`~!/@\#}$%:;)(_^{&*=|+]+$" ValidationGroup="vgTags" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnAddTag" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgTags" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddTag_Click" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <div id="divTags">
                                <asp:PlaceHolder id="plhTags" runat="server" />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTags" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderTooltip="Disable" ItemStyle-Width="1%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="IsActive" UniqueName="IsActive" ReadOnly="true">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibnDisabledProcess" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Images/Icons/Stop.png" Width="16"
                                OnClientClick="return window.confirm('Activate this Process?');"
                                ToolTip="Click to activate this Request for Account use." Visible='<%#IIF(Eval("IsActive"),false,true) %>' OnClick="ibnDisableToggleProcess_Click" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibnEnabledProcess" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Images/Icons/Stop_disabled.png" Width="16"
                                OnClientClick="return window.confirm('Deactivate this Process?');"
                                ToolTip="Click to deactivate this Request for Account use." Visible='<%#IIF(Eval("IsActive"),true,false) %>' OnClick="ibnDisableToggleProcess_Click" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDisableProcessID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Is Active" UniqueName="IsActiveCheckbox" Display="false">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxIsActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# IIF(Eval("IsActive") Is DbNull.Value OrElse Eval("IsActive") = False,False,True) %>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" EditText="Edit Admin" ItemStyle-Width="16" EditImageUrl="~/Images/edit-small.png" />

                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Do you really want to delete this Admin? WARNING: THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE!!" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                        ConfirmTitle="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete Admin" ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.png"
                        UniqueName="DeleteColumn">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="16" />
                    </telerik:GridButtonColumn>

                </Columns>

                <DetailTables>

                    <%-----------------------------------------------------------%>
                    <%-------------------------- FORMS --------------------------%>
                    <%-----------------------------------------------------------%>
                    <telerik:GridTableView Name="gtvForms"
                            AllowPaging="true"
                            PagerStyle-Position="TopAndBottom"
                            PageSize="20"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            DataKeyNames="RequestFormPacketID,ID"
                            runat="server"
                            CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                            Width="100%">

                        <ParentTableRelation>
                            <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="RequestFormPacketID" MasterKeyField="ID" />
                        </ParentTableRelation>

                        <CommandItemTemplate>
                            <table width="100%" class="AdminGridHeaders">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="AdminGridHeaders">
                                        &nbsp;<img src="../Admin/Images/Forms.png" align="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Forms
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Button ID="ibnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Form" CommandName="InitInsert" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </CommandItemTemplate>

                        <EditFormSettings>
                            <EditColumn ButtonType="PushButton" InsertText="Save" UpdateText="Update" CancelText="Cancel" />
                        </EditFormSettings>

                        <EditItemStyle Font-Bold="true" BackColor="#FFFFCC"  />

                        <Columns>

                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Form Name" UniqueName="FormName">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <img src="../Admin/Images/Forms.png" align="absmiddle" width="16" height="16" style="margin-right:4px;" /> <%#Eval("Form.Name")%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbForms" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsForms" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("FormID")%>'>
                                        <Items>
                                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="-- Select a Form --" Value="" />
                                        </Items>
                                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvForms" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="rcbForms" InitialValue="-- Select a Form --" Display="Dynamic" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Test" ReadOnly="true" UniqueName="TestForm" HeaderStyle-Width="1%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypTestForm" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "FormsPreview.aspx?fid=" & Eval("FormID").ToString() & "&test=true" %>' Target="_blank"><asp:Image ID="imgTestProcess" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Admin/Images/Test.png" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="Test Form" /></asp:HyperLink>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Header" SortExpression="Header" UniqueName="Header">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("Form.Header")%>&nbsp;
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="1%" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
                                UniqueName="SortOrder">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibnItemUpArrow" runat="server" Width="16" height="16" ImageUrl="~/Admin/Images/ArrowUp.png" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" Visible='<%#IIF(Eval("SortOrder") = 0,false,true) %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' OnCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work at least once? `ItemDataBound` doesn't run on postback, so your events won't get rewired if a postback occurs. You should be using `ItemCreated` instead:

- [Event sequence](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdeventsequence.html)
- [Distinguishing the major differences between ItemCreated and ItemDataBound events](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grddistinguishdifferencesbetweenitemcreateditemdatabound.html)

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense.  I was using the DataItem in this Sub though so I don't think I can do that within ItemCreated so I'll just have to find a work around for that part.

Comment: Hmm - based on your very helpful links, it looks like I need to split this up a little.  Add the handler in the ItemCreated and do all the data work in the ItemDataBound somehow.  Hopefully, I'll be able to do that.  Thanks for your help!